# Python - Add leading 0 to file numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and programming generally
I have 1200 text files in a folder, in the following format:
James - 1 - How to... .txt
Sarah - 2 - How to... .txt
Steph - 3 - How to... .txt
...
Mariah - 200 - How to... .txt
...
Rashford - 1200 - How to... .txt

I want to rename the files below 1000 to add leading 0's so they all have the same number of digits, for instance, 0001, 0050, 0300

This is my code so far, but am stuck:

```
#!python3

import os
from tkinter import filedialog

cleaned_files = []

root_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(root_folder)
folder_files = os.listdir(root_folder)

# Filter out files starting with '.' and '_'
cleaned_files = []
for item in folder_files:
    if item[0] == '.' or item[0] == '_':
        pass
    else:
        cleaned_files.append(item)


# Find file names of the root folder and save them


def getFiles(files):
    for file in files:
        file_start, file_number, file_end = file.split('-')
        file_number.strip()

        # Was trying to append just one 0 to numbers <10
        if int(file_number) < 10:
            print(file_number)
        else:
            pass
getFiles(cleaned_files)
```

Comment: You want to use `str.zfill()` - this will add leading zeros to your strings where required

Comment: @gtlambert could you please show me an example of how to rename after adding the zeros

Comment: You really need to narrow down your question to something specific - then I can help in detail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you were said in comments, `str.zfill` is one possible and simple solution.

You have just to change your `getfiles` function:

```
def getFiles(files):
    for file in files:
        file_start, file_number, file_end = file.split('-')
        num = file_number.split().zfill(4)  # num is 4 characters long with leading 0

        new_file = "{}- {} -{}".format(file_start, num, file_end)
        # rename or store the new file name for later rename
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify your append method like this (mentioned by @gtlambert and @zondo):

```
    # Was trying to append just one 0 to numbers <10
    file_number.zfill(4)
```

[Python string zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill)